# Adding an image as background in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to set the image in the background, I have created an assets folder under the project name and paste the image in it, and I wrote below code. but it is showing error like this,

```
I/flutter (13556): 
I/flutter (13556): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (13556): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (13556): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (13556): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:383:44)
I/flutter (13556): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (13556): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:368:14)
I/flutter (13556): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anon`enter code here`ymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:265:86)
I/flutter (13556): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:82:22)
I/flutter (13556): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:265:63)
I/flutter (13556): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (13556): 
I/flutter (13556): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/app_icon.png")
I/flutter (13556): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#3950b(), name: "assets/app_icon.png",
I/flutter (13556): scale: 1.0)
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage("assets/app_icon.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: null /* add child content content here */,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: "When the exception was thrown" the most essential part of the error output seems to be missing. The lines before should tell what the exception was. Also the exception output is quite useless without seeing the code that caused it.

Comment: the Code i'm using is here                                                                  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage("assets/app_icon.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: null /* add child content content here */,
      ),
    );
  }

Comment: Did you add the assets to your pubspec.yaml assets?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments loses its formatting and is unreadable.

Comment: Yes I added the assets in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: @Gunter told you to reformat your code but still you haven't did that yet. So, I also cannot understand the question to answer. Sorry!

Comment: I updated my code with proper understandable can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: I am not getting the error but the image does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Check "tabs" in pubspec.yaml.

Should be tabbed at one level from "flutter:" i.e, at the same level as say "uses-material-design: true"

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
   - images/myimagename.png
```

**NOT**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
assets:
   - images/xxx.png
```